# Is there way to use ControlSend or something else without grabbing focus

Tags: autoit

I have two windows. I want to control first window with my real mouse and keybord, and at the same time i want to control second window with autoit script wich will be send prepared data of mouse clicks or keybord. But second window must do it without grabbing focus from first window. Is it real?

Comment: Yeah, that's possible. That's where the `Control...`-functions come into play... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

For sure. See Control... commands. 
You may also have a look at AutoitSetOption ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why not. That is all the person needs to do. Just use the ControlCommands like ControlSend, ControlSetText and so on. With the correct options those commands will work on even on hidden child windows without taking the focus. Sometimes the answer is so easy, so why posting it in a comment?